# Syntax error in case statement while creating MySQL view

Tags: mysql

I am getting mysql #1064 error while trying to create a view

```
CREATE VIEW trip_summary AS select `driver_details`.`DriverId`, CONCAT(driver_details.Firstname, ' ', driver_details.Lastname, ' ', driver_details.TaxiPlateNo) AS TaxiDriver, count(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TotalTrip, GROUP_CONCAT(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TripIds, sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) AS TotalTripDistance, sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) AS TotalTripFare from `driver_details` left join `taxi_trip` on (`taxi_trip`.`DriverId` = `driver_details`.`DriverId` and `taxi_trip`.`PickupLAT` != 0 and `taxi_trip`.`DropLAT` != 0 and `taxi_trip`.`TotalFare` != 0) where taxi_trip.AutoId!=0 and 
  CASE WHEN `DriverIdFun`()!='' THEN taxi_trip.DriverId = `DriverIdFun`()
  END AS field1,
  CASE WHEN `From_Date`()!='' THEN taxi_trip.RequestDate >= `From_Date`()
  END AS field2,
  CASE WHEN `To_Date`()!='' THEN taxi_trip.RequestDate <= `To_Date`()
  END AS field3 group by taxi_trip.DriverId
```

Comment: Of course you do. That's invalid SQL. You copied that from somewhere? Do you know what `WHERE` clause does and where `CASE` should be used?

Comment: no.. I am not aware of where case

Comment: So how about you learn SQL first before asking people to debug stuff for you?

Comment: Whats the problem in asking help how can i learn new things?

Comment: You learn new things by reading manuals, code etc. You're not learning here, you obviously have some sort of job you can't do and you are asking other people to debug stuff for you. It's absolute bullshit you're learning, you're getting work done for free here. You're telling us that you found how to create a view, do CASE comparison and joining but you don't know what `WHERE` clause is? You think you're the first one who has no clue about programming and tried to use SO to copy paste stuff that "geeks" here provide? Btw. a beginner would solve this problem. You know 0 about SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct query to create the view which i need

```
CREATE VIEW trip_summary AS
select
`driver_details`.`DriverId`,
CONCAT(driver_details.Firstname, ' ', driver_details.Lastname, ' ',
driver_details.TaxiPlateNo) AS TaxiDriver,
count(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TotalTrip,
GROUP_CONCAT(taxi_trip.AutoId) AS TripIds,
sum(taxi_trip.TripDistance) AS TotalTripDistance,
sum(taxi_trip.TotalFare) AS TotalTripFare
from `driver_details`
left join `taxi_trip`
on (`taxi_trip`.`DriverId` = `driver_details`.`DriverId`
and `taxi_trip`.`PickupLAT` != 0
and `taxi_trip`.`DropLAT` != 0
and `taxi_trip`.`TotalFare` != 0)
where taxi_trip.AutoId!=0
and
CASE
    WHEN `DriverIdFun`()!=''
        THEN taxi_trip.DriverId = `DriverIdFun`()
    ELSE
        TRUE
END
AND
CASE
    WHEN `From_Date`()!=''
        THEN taxi_trip.RequestDate >= `From_Date`()
    ELSE
        TRUE
END
AND
CASE
    WHEN `To_Date`()!=''
        THEN taxi_trip.RequestDate <= `To_Date`()
    ELSE
        TRUE
END
group by taxi_trip.DriverId
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but may contain enough info to get you started....

Typically (but not everytime), a VIEW into a set of database tables does not have a WHERE clause, and in your case the WHERE clause looks like a dog's breakfast.

I'd start with this much simpler view and develop from here....

```
CREATE VIEW trip_summary AS 
SELECT 
  dd.`DriverId`, 
  CONCAT(dd.Firstname, ' ', dd.Lastname, ' ', dd.TaxiPlateNo) AS TaxiDriver, 
  count(tt.AutoId) AS TotalTrip, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(tt.AutoId) AS TripIds, 
  sum(tt.TripDistance) AS TotalTripDistance,
  sum(tt.TotalFare) AS TotalTripFare
FROM `driver_details` AS dd
LEFT JOIN `taxi_trip` AS tt 
ON tt.`DriverId` = dd.`DriverId` 
  AND tt.`PickupLAT` != 0 
  AND tt.`DropLAT` != 0 
  AND tt.`TotalFare` != 0
GROUP BY tt.DriverId
```

Then when you query the view, you select what you do and don't want out of the view by means of the where clause

```
SELECT * FROM trip_summary WHERE DriverID=1234;
```

Comment: No.. It was not correct one since i need to pass the values driver id, start date and end date as parameters based on the selections done in the view page

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a SQL view is, It is not a view into a single item, it is a representation of multiple tables of data as an (apparently) single table. Whatever this view page is, it's likely to be doing it wrong. Edit your example to show the code for the "view page"

Comment: @bakoyaro Some you win, some you lose :D    
sujivasagam seems to have answered the question himself, but his answer is not really a view so much as a complete SQL Query within a view.